# How to group by month with days

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I could use the help. I have a data set which I need to filter down. The data looks like this:

| code | date | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| code1 | 20210713 | 1.0000000000 |
| code1 | 20210719 | 4.0000000000 |
| code1 | 20210726 | 3.0000000000 |

code is nvarchar(85)
date is nvarchar(10)
quantity is numeric(38,15)

I'm tasked to get a list of data for the one code (code1). This data needs to show the quantity grouped by date. In months.

What's best way to do this with a bit of explanation behind it?

Comment: *date is nvarchar(10)*  - so it's not a date then, it's a string. Have you looked at the date/time functions provided by your specific RDBMS?

Comment: **Never** store date or date/time values in `varchar` columns.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use the function `MONTH()`to get the month of a date. SQL will implicitly convert a valid string to a date. We then `GROUP BY` month and code specifiying the code we want with `WHERE`.
NB the function `MONTH()`does not funciton in all dbms. Please specify which flavour of SQL you are using.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE dataset (
>   code varchar(10),
>   date varchar(10),
>   quantity decimal(10,8)
>   );
> INSERT INTO dataset values
> ('code1','20210613',1.0000000000),
> ('code1','20210719',4.0000000000),
> ('code1','20210726',3.0000000000);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>    d.code,
>    MONTH(d.date) "month"
> FROM 
>    dataset d
> WHERE
>    d.code = 'code1'
> GROUP BY
>    d.code,
>    MONTH(d.date)
> ORDER BY 
>    d.code,
>    MONTH(d.date);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> code  | month
> :---- | ----:
> code1 |     6
> code1 |     7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=947ba0cf7558b06de8a13c81d8405113)*

If you want to only return a certain date range you can specify the year in the `WHERE`clause as follows:

```
WHERE
   d.code = 'code1'
   AND YEAR(d.date) = 2021
```

or you can specify first and last dates, which is longer to write, but more flexible.

```
WHERE
   d.code = 'code1'
   AND d.date > '20201231'
   AND d.date < '20230101'
```

Comment: This works well! Thank you very much. Just one question, this script is going to be run on a live site in which creating a table is the best idea, can I use a CTE or something similar so it doesn't create anything in the database?  

Also, where you have the insert, what if I have like 900k rows which I need to sift through using the WHERE() clause.

Comment: The first part of the script with create table is only setting up for the test. When you run the query you only want to run the second part starting from SELECT. You need to check/modify the table and column names with the 'real' table. Please accept the answer if it answers your question. Thank you

Comment: If I add to the select SUM(columnwithdata) as total will this SUM that total up by month?

Comment: Yes it should do - try, test and check, as always

Comment: Works just as I would like it to. Thank you very much for you help, I'm sure there will be many more queries from me that you have the knowledge too.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. How can I force this to look at a certain date range? Say I want to look at all months within 2021.

Comment: please see edit at the end of the answer